# Tensorflow: How to get the correct output of a pretrained Keras model with inputs from another Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras pre-trained model "model_keras" and I want to use it in a loss function. The input of model "model_keras" is an output of another Tensorflow model "model_tf" (a generative model). I'm trying to update the weights of "model_tf" by minimizing the loss. During the optimization, "model_kears" is only used for inference and will not get updated. My problem is that I'm not able to get the correct inference result from "model_keras", due to this issue, I'm not able to update the "model_tf" correctly. The code is shown below:

```
    loss_func(input, target, model_keras): # the input is an output of another Tensorflow model.
      inference_res = model_keras(input)
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(inference_res-target)
    return loss
```

```
    train_phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    model_tf = Generator("generator") # Building the Tensorflow model "model_tf"
    fake_img = model_tf(z, train_phase, y, NUMS_CLASS) # fake_img is the output of "model_tf" and will be served as the input of "model_keras"
    model_keras = MyKerasModel("Vgg19") # Loading the pretrained Keras model
    G_loss = loss_func(fake_img, t, model_keras)
    G_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(4e-4, beta1=0., beta2=0.9).minimize(G_loss, var_list=model_tf.var_list())
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(G_opt, feed_dict={z: Z, train_phase: True, y: Y, t: target}) # Z, Y and target are numpy arrays.
```

I also tried to use model.predict(input) but got the ValueError: "When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size". Reason behind is that model.predict() expects the input to be real data tensor instead of a symbolic tensor. However, since I want to update the weights of "model_tf", I need to make the loss function differentiable and compute the gradients. Therefore, I can not just pass a numpy array to "model_keras".

How can I get the correct output(inference_res) of "model_keras" in this case? The Tensorflow and Keras version I'm using is 1.15 and 2.2.5, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, here is an idea. You can pass your input to `model_keras` and lets name the output `keras_y`. Then freeze the `model_keras` and add the model to the end of `model_tf` so you have a big `model` which is sequence of `model_tf` and then `model_keras` (which the second part has been freezed). Next give the inputs to your `model` and name the output as `model_y`. Now you can compute the loss as `loss_func(keras_y, model_y)`

Comment: Thanks. Your understanding is correct. The way I'm constructing the model now is similar to the way you suggested. However, the issue still exists because the model_keras can't perform a correct forward pass output. Do you know how Keras perform the forward pass computation in Tensorflow?

Comment: What do you mean by "model_keras can't perform a correct forward pass output"? what is wrong there? does it give an error or what?

Comment: When Keras executes inference_res = model_keras(input), it doesn't give the correct output. I'm not sure how Keras executes this command internally. I also tried K.function however it requires the input to be a data tensor as well. The current workaround I have is that I extracted all the parameters from the Keras model and I wrote a new Tensorflow model for feed-forward computation by loading these parameters. It's very time consuming but it works...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help about that. But I suggest you to have a new post about this problem and put the related code there, as I think you got your answer for this posts topic.